# What's the recommended caching strategy for iterative compuation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application running stage compuations - that is,
1. Compute with the input of large dataset on AWS S3 (`ds: data-original`), produce filtered results (`ds1: data-intermediate`), and save the `ds1` to AWS S3.
2. And in the same application, continue to process (filter) `ds1: data-intermediate` and produce the final result `ds2: data-final`.
3. Perform some actions on `ds2`, and then save the `ds2` to AWS S3.

So the processing is like:

```
ds -> ds1
//ds1.persist()
ds1.write.save(...)
ds1 -> ds2
ds2.cache()
ds2.count
ds2.distinct
ds2.write.save(...)
```

The data size of ds/ds1/ds2 is like 100GB, 10GB, 1GB respectively.
I want to use RDD caching to avoid redundant computation, but also want to avoid unnecessary SerDes and disk IO.

My question is, if I don't persist `ds1` as shown by the line `//ds1.persist()`, will spark app re-compute the `ds1` when it computes `ds1 -> ds2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have few options, from fast and expensive to slow and cheap:

- `df.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)` caches dataframe to RAM of the cluster. Is very fast if you have enough memory. Became excellent option after the change in AWS pricing model to per second. Drawback: if you have a complex pipeline, which you run on spot instances fail of one instance causes failure of whole computation.
- `df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)` is slower, but still a good option since data a cached to local storages of Spark executors.  It has the same drawback as option 1.
- Save intermediate computations to HDFS in the efficient format (columnar like parquet in most cases). It should be close to option 2 in performance terms and are tolerant to spot instance failure if you run it on EMR.
- Save intermediate computations to S3, which is slowest one, but maybe a good option, if you run transient cluster and the possibility of failure in the middle, is significant.

Note, that in options 3 and you have to save and then load new dataframe to cut computation graph.

Comment: Thanks! You advice is useful! And I edited my question,i.e., if I comment `ds1.persist()`,  will spark app re-compute the ds1 when it computes `ds1 -> ds2`?

Comment: If `df` is `Dataset` `df.cache()` is identical as `df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)`

Comment: 1) yes since ds1 immutable, ds1.write.save(...) does not affect its computation, if you want to cut expensive computation graph, you have to save and then load df 2) yes, you're right, default persists level is MEMORY_AND_DISK, so cache do the same.  I correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly, there are no actions anywhere except the actions on top of `d2(the final result)`. Since spark transformations are lazy, unless it encounters an action, previous RDDs will not be materialized. To answer your question:

> if I don't persist ds1 as shown by the line
>   //ds1.persist(), will spark app re-compute the ds1 when it computes
>   ds1 -> ds2?

even if you are caching/persisting `ds1`, it will not computed until you do count/distinct on `ds2`. so `ds1` is not "recomputed", as its computed for the first time.

Your processing can be:

```
1)ds -> ds1
2)ds1 -> ds2
3)ds2.cache()
4)ds2.count  //your first action. at this point ds1 & ds2 will be computed & cached
5)ds2.distinct  // will not compute ds1 & ds2 again as its cached previously.
6)ds2.write.save(...) // assuming you are not storing d2 directly but after some transformation/action on top of d2. if you just want to save d2, then do write.save(..) on line 3 instead.
```

Comment: I think you missed the action `ds1.write.save(...)`. This will triger the compuation of `ds1`, right? So come back to my question, should I cache `ds1` before continue to `ds2`?

Comment: Yes, ds1.write.save will trigger the computation. But you have to read it again from the saved location and use it, instead of using the same rdd